# page overflowing in table environment due to content outside tabulars

Tags: tables

We made a command to print our software requirements but now that we hit things that use a lot of space we have an overflow issue.

We used a `table` environment to keep everything together and avoid weird things like a final bar ending up on a different page but this clearly is a hack.
I use two `tabular`s as writing text in a huge table cell was frustrating that a white line didn't results in a paragraph brake anymore.

How do I change this such that the overflows are gone and if a requirement gets spread over 2 pages each part has at least a few lines of content? Preferably without having to edit to much cases where this is already used?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcommand{\requirement}[5]{  
  \begin{table}[H]
  \begin{tabular*} {\textwidth} {  p{0.70\textwidth} r } 
    \toprule
    \emph{#3} & \textbf{ID.#1.#2} \\
    \midrule
  \end{tabular*}
    #4    

   \vspace{10pt}
    \textbf{Motivation:}\\
    #5

  \vspace{-5pt}
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{}p{\textwidth}} 
      \bottomrule
  \end{tabular*}
  \end{table}
}

\begin{document}
long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long
long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\

\requirement{R}{6}{Name}
{Requirement way to long
long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long

long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long

long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long

long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long
}
{motivation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}


\newcommand{\requirement}[5]{\par
\smallskip
\hrule
\nopagebreak
\noindent{\large\strut}\textit{#3}\hfill\textbf{ID.#1.#2}
\par
\nopagebreak
\hrule
\par
\nopagebreak
\smallskip
\clubpenalty10000
#4 \par
\par
\nopagebreak
\hrule
\noindent{\large\strut}\textbf{Motivation:}\par
\smallskip
\clubpenalty10000
#5\par
\par
\nopagebreak
\hrule
\par
}


\begin{document}
\requirement{R}{6}{Name}
{Requirement way to long
long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\
long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\
long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\
long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long
}
{motivation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, first experiments with this look very promissing and I think I can solve everything I want this way. And I learned something about widows and orphans by looking up with a clubpenalty is :)

Answer (score 4):

Use a `longtable`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{booktabs,longtable,array}

\newcommand{\requirement}[5]{%
  \begin{longtable}[l]{@{}p{0.70\textwidth}>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr0.30\textwidth-4\tabcolsep}}
    \toprule
    \emph{#3} & \textbf{ID.#1.#2} \\
    \midrule
    #4

  \end{longtable}
   \vspace{10pt}
    \noindent\textbf{Motivation:}\par    
    \noindent#5

  \vspace{-5pt}
    \noindent\rule{\linewidth}{1pt}%
}


\begin{document}
\requirement{R}{6}{Name}
{Requirement way to long
long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\
long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\
long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\
long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\long\\
}
{motivation}

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: The problem with longtable is that it still allows ugly things like a single bar at the end and empty lines still don't register as paragraphs which means I would have to scan hundreds of lines to do something to make paragraphs works.
I updated the original example to show it just leaving a single line and the paragraph breaks not working